# Need a Excel script to identify email addresses that contain a different variation of the first name of the contact

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba, vbscript

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 50k+ rows of data, where we are trying to identify within the rows of data where the email address has no match of the first name, etc.

We are basically trying to narrow down the rows to as few as possible where email addresses have a different variation of their first name so that we can replace the salutation field with that info.

So, if there name is Jonathan Smith in column `O` (there are variances in the name field, some names have middle initials, etc.) and their email address in column `R` is 
johnsmith@gmail.com, we want to update the Salutation field in column `X` with "John".

I realize some of this will have to be done manually but we are trying to narrow 
down those 50k rows to get the obvious ones that don't qualify (ones that have the 
same first name or first initial last name or last name first initial in the email address) out of the way.

I got it narrowed down from 50k to 15k by doing the following:

First I used the formula `=1-ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&LEFT(O2,3)&"*",R2,0))` which helped me rule out emails that matched part of the contacts first name. (obviously doing it this way I won't catch "Rob" against "Robert" but I can't figure out any other way).

Then, I sorted the data to get the ones that matched, out of the equation. On the ones that didn't match, I did another formula to extract first initial last name using `=PROPER(LEFT(O2)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(O2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))`. This did not give me any that had a middle initial, (those should be ruled out as well as I see quite a few like "jrsmith" but I only get "jsmith").

Then, from there I did `=1-ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&LEFT(W2,3)&"*",R2,0))` to see if any emails matched those so I could rule those out.

Again, I got it from 50k down to 15k but there has to be an easier way. Is there an easier way? Like a nested function or script that would look at this spreadsheet and identify rows where the email address does not contain variations of:

- lastnamefirstname@
- firstinitiallastname@
- firstinitialmiddleinitiallastname@
- Firstname (complete match)@
- firstnamelastname@

Comment: Is the common element the first name? So if the first string in the name column (space delimited) matches any string in the email column, it is to be excluded?

Comment: Potentially.  However have to be careful as the first name may be John and the email contains Johnathan (which we would want to keep as they are different).

Comment: Well if that was the case, would you want it to be flagged for review, or not flagged for review? What I'm thinking is excel can look for the partial string in the email string and flag or highlight all that don't contain it.

Comment: Instead of flag for review, could it just pull the first half of the email address (before the @) in a new column and could it sort so all the ones for review are together at the top so we don't have to scroll thru 50k?  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, insert an extra column and adjust the range and offsets to search in the appropriate place. Then just sort by non-blanks in the new column to see all that don't match.

```
Sub firstname()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For Each c In Range("A:A")
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", c.Value)
        strName = Left(c, i - 1)
        strName = UCase(strName)
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("@", c.Offset(0, 2).Value)
        strEmail = Left(c.Offset(0, 2), j - 1)
        strEmail = UCase(strEmail)

            If InStr(strEmail, strName) = 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = strEmail
            End If

    End If
 Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note: this doesn't account for the John vs Johnathan condition**

Comment: Took awhile for me to figure out what is what but this looks like it will only give me if first and last name is a complete match (including case, so if the contact name is propercase, the email has to be too) That won't work.  Also, I needed to weed out the first initial last name variations as well.  Anyway that can be added?  Thanks for your help.  I understand if it cant be done.

Comment: Is there anyway to nest the functions I did, into one? So if one doesn't match but the other does, it will still mark it for me to ignore? NOTE: O is Contact R=Email =1-ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&LEFT(O2,3)&"*",R2,0)) which helped me rule out emails that matched part of the contacts first name. (obviously doing it this way I won't catch Rob against Robert but Can't figure out any other way).

Comment: Here is the rest: I did another formula to extract first initial last name using =PROPER(LEFT(O2)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(O2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))) This did not give me any that had a middle initial, (those should be ruled out as well as I see quite a few like jrsmith but I only get jsmith). 

Then from there I did  =1-ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&LEFT(W2,3)&"*",R2,0)) to see if any emails matched those so I could rule those out.

Comment: What about John Smith's email being `CptJSmith` or `CplJohnS`? How many variations are you trying to find? As those increase, the likelihod of automating it decreases.

Comment: I realize we will have to look at some manually but would like to narrow down as much as possible.  Obviously those above do not meet the criteria so I don't need to see them but I understand that I will come across items like that.  Ultimately anything before the @ sign in the email field that is different from the first name in the contact field (with the exception of firstinitial lastname, etc.) we should look at to see if there is a viable first name that is different. See my original email where I specified "where the email address does not contain variations of..."  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The macro I wrote compares the first name to the email address and shows you every email that doesn't contain the first name. `SEARCH` isn't case-sensitive, but `FIND` is.

Comment: I just tested and it's case sensitive. (the contact John Smith is proper case, the macro doesn't work correctly when the email is johnsmith but works fine when it's Johnsmith.  Anyway to fix that?:(  Can you also have it ignore first intial last name?  That would be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: Just touching base, are you able to assist me further with the above?  Please advise.  Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: @lmp yeah it should work now. I was incorrect about the case, I don't know why the MS Library was wrong, maybe I looked at the incorrect year. And by "work" I don't mean I've done anything about the last name part. Only first name. The issue with first initial and last name is that there are middle names, it's difficult to get the strings unless you run operations on each delimiter and then pull `left` and `right`

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to do it for first intial last name?  I realize some have middle intials but I am trying to omit as much as possible and there are a lot of first intial last names. So if you can make it if the first intial and last name match the email, leave the one field blank. Then I can ignore them.  It that not possible (obviously if there is a middle intial, it wont match and it will put the email in the field, which is fine.  It will still help me. :)  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just tested your changes from earlier. works perfect.  If we could just do the first intial last name as well, I would be set! :) Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sure you know your data structure well enough to use what I've given you to extract delimited strings and then use `left` and `right` to get what you need.

Comment: I know my data but I don't know vba, etc (?) and your response loses me (extract delimited strings, left? Right?).  The formulas I used were copied from the internet (doing searches on things similar to what I need).  I look at your code and have no idea. :(  I am in awe of people such as yourself who do this and hope to learn it some day. It's not in my cards at the moment as my company will not pay for me to learn during work hours and I have small children at home.  Is it hard to do these revisions I ask?  Can you please help.  My area of expertise is Act! contact management software.

Comment: Can you use [text to columns](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261) to parse the data and then adjust the macro?

Comment: That is just it. Adjust the macro how? It is foreign to me.  :(

Comment: I need a tweak to this if possible.  I have the contacts initials i.e., JS or CM or LP, etc.and I would like to match it to the first two characters in the email (before the @)  I tried with the code above but it doesn't work. (maybe because there is no space with intials.  Do I need to submit a new question and just copy the code above to ask for a modification.  My apologies for not understanding the process yet.